# Is there a way to access GA4 data with PHP without composer?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-api-php-client

Before GA4, I was able to get page views from UA via the old google api.   That worked great.  After we switched to GA4 though, we are no longer seeing new page views.

It's my understanding I have to install the "php-analytics-data" library to access this?

The main instructions are to install this with composer, but long story short, composer is not an option here.  I would love to install https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data without composer, but I don't see a way to do this?

For example this is the V1beta dir which seems promising:  https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data/tree/master/src/V1beta .  But typically you would load the autoload file first, but as this wouldn't be installed by composer, how would I do this?

The following is an example of GA4 stat retrieval using composer...how do I do the equivalent without?

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/[YOUR_PROPERTY_ID]'
]);

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    foreach ($row->getDimensionValues() as $dimensionValue) {
        print 'Dimension Value: ' . $dimensionValue->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Composer is just a convenient installer tool. Nothing stops you copying the code files and working out the dependencies yourself, if that's what you have to do.  Composer merely automates that process.

Answer (score 1):

> The following is an example of GA4 stat retrieval using composer...how do I do the equivalent without?

Just remove the first line where the composer autoloader is obtained. But that requires that you install the package manually:

> I would love to install https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data without composer, but I don't see a way to do this?

Can you explain why composer is not an option? It is the state-of-the-art package manager for PHP. As you can see in the repositories [composer.json](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data/blob/master/composer.json), there are library requirements which might not be installed for you when you do not install this library without composer. To be fair, it *is* possible to install this library without composer:

1. Download repository and add its source files to your project
2. Configure your autoloader to also load these library files
3. Search for dependencies from that library
4. Continue with step 1

As you can see, this is a lot of work to get all the packages you need to run php-analytics-data .

> But typically you would load the autoload file first, but as this wouldn't be installed by composer, how would I do this?

Install composer, then type `$ composer require google/analytics-data` in your terminal and use the code you provided as example. Its really easy as that, just give composer a try.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do have composer installed but it doesn't work.  Your command stalls for five minutes and then generates an error " [RuntimeException]                     
  Error Output: sh: 1: php55: not found ".  This is an old server...an upgrade is scheduled but not  yet.  I'm on php 7.0, but I'm not sure why php55 is showing an error.  This is composer 1...it's kind of a mess...that why I was hoping to install the library manually.

Comment: @daniel S welcome to stack please read [how to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) while i appreciate your extra information its best to stick with the question as it is asked rather then giving your unsolicited opinion as to what systems the author should or should not be using.   Not everyone can or wants to use composer, that's their prerogative and a lot of times dedicated by others and out of the developers control.